# How to transform list of tree diameters by species into frequencies

Tags: r, reshape

I am into forestry. Relatively new to R; used read.csv,  [, ], names, ifelse, changed variable type, made simple calculations, rbind dataframes, that kind of stuff.

I have a dataframe containing tallies of tree diameters (in 2 cm classes: 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.) listed by species. So, I have one variable for each species and as many lines per plot as there are trees in the most frequent species. Plots are grouped in forest stands. The plot number is not unique since it can appear in other stands. Here is an example of what it may look like for one particular plot:

```
Stand      Plot    SM    RM    YB    WB    Others  
108504     1       2     6     12    32    24  
108504     1       8     8     10    
108504     1       8     8     12  
108504     1       8     4     8  
...
```

I want to transform that dataframe so to have one line per plot and each combination of species and diameter becoming a new variable containing the number of trees of that diameter and species.Here is how I would like this to appear:

```
Stand      Plot    SM2    SM8    RM4    RM6    RM8    YB8    YB10    YB12    WB32    Others24  
108504     1       1      3      1      1      2      1      1       2       1       1
```

I think I first need to compute the frequencies by diameters, by plot, by stand. I would guess, I would need to do a set of imbricated apply sort of loops. Don't know how to do that though. After that, I guess I would need to generate new variable names where the result of those frequencies would be put. Thanks for your help.

From comments received I may add that the intended use of this is mainly to:
1- compute  density and basal area (total and by species) by plot
2- output stand tables for each plot to a growth and yield simulation model.

Comment: You probably have a good reason for this, but could you explain why you want this format? Having information in column headers is not 'tidy data' (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)

Comment: We can use `data.table` to do this.

Comment: Maybe that is because I am not very familiar with apply family of commands. Maybe if I master these techniques, I could manage with one line per stand, plot, diameter and a column for each species.

Comment: @MartinBéland what do you want to do with the data in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that will get you data in a long (instead of a wide) format:

```
dat <-read.table(text="Stand      Plot    SM    RM    YB    WB    Others  
108504     1       2     6     12    32    24  
108504     1       8     8     10   0 0
108504     1       8     8     12  0 0
108504     1       8     4     8 0 0", header=T)

library(reshape2)

dat$line_id <- 1:nrow(dat) #you can do without, but I like to save this

#melt
m_dat <- melt(dat, id.var=c("Stand","Plot","line_id"),
              variable.name="species",value.name="diameter")

m_dat <- m_dat[m_dat$diameter!=0,] #artefact of reading in data...

#aggregate again (if necessary, based on counts)
res <- dcast(m_dat, Stand+Plot+species+diameter~"count",value.var="diameter",fun.agg=length)
> res
    Stand Plot species diameter count
1  108504    1      SM        2     1
2  108504    1      SM        8     3
3  108504    1      RM        4     1
4  108504    1      RM        6     1
5  108504    1      RM        8     2
6  108504    1      YB        8     1
7  108504    1      YB       10     1
8  108504    1      YB       12     2
9  108504    1      WB       32     1
10 108504    1  Others       24     1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `doBy` and `reshape` libraries. Here is the solution for your task.
You can also do it also with `dplyR`.

```
library(doBy); library(reshape)
# Create a test data frame
data.df <- data.frame(Stand = rep(c(108504,108505), each = 10),
                   Plot = rep(c(1,2)),
                   SM = round(runif(10,1,10),0),
                   RM = round(runif(10,1,10),0),
                   YB = round(runif(10,1,10),0))

#first melt the data
data <- melt(data.df, id = c("Stand","Plot"))

# create an ID for class (tree species + dbh class
data$Tree_ID <- paste(data$variable, data$value, sep = "_")

# make the summary of the data using length
data <- summaryBy(value ~ Stand + Plot + Tree_ID, data = data, FUN = length, keep.names = T)

# transform it back to the format you need
data <- cast(data, Stand + Plot ~ Tree_ID, vaue = value)
```